# Need word for situation where conclusion doesn't follow from the experimental data

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need a more specific word than *illogical*.

Say an educational psychologist collected some data about someone by having two people fill out a questionnaire that is a well known, reputable, published, normed instrument.  The two questionnaires yielded totally different results, and then the psychologist "resolved" the "discrepancy" by conveniently throwing out the questionnaire that didn't support the conclusion he wanted to draw.

I think we don't say his conclusion is *fallacious*.  I think we can say it is *illogical*.  Is there a more specific, apt word for this situation?  A single word if possible.

Comment: The scientist and his conclusion are *biased*.

Comment: I added _biased_ too as an answer; probably I was editing my answer while you were editing your comment.

Comment: I think it's a phrase:  Unsupported by evidence.

Comment: *Mendelevian* comes to mind; not only did Mendel selectively bias the evidence (an early triumph of modern statistics was to show that the likelihood that all of the data that he used was the way he said it was, was trillions to one against), but it turned out that the particular species he used does not behave genetically in the way he claimed.

Comment: If valid data is selectively chosen, the pracitice is _dishonest_.

Comment: Throwing one of two tests (or fifty of one hundred tests) out of a study because they yield data incompatible with the researcher' favored result amounts to willfully skewing the research results. I would refer to the conclusions drawn from such a selectively gathered data set as **doctored**, **artificially cultivated**, or **groomed**, because the data set is **nonreproducible under scientific conditions**.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Helpful.  I also really like the phrase "because they yield data incompatible with the researcher's favored result" and "wilfully skewing the research results".  Perhaps you could move this to an answer?  It would make it easier for me to harvest all this great stuff.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Great word!  How about an answer?

Comment: Thanks, aparente001. My comment doesn't meet the minimum standards of a formal EL&U answer, in my opinion, and I don't feel that my doing the supporting research necessary to turn it into one would make it any more useful to you. But I'm glad you found the bare suggestions helpful.

Comment: I could not improve on @Sven Yargs' explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ***biased*** and also ***subjective***.

M-W:

> [**biased**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biased)
>   *adjective*
>
> : having or showing a bias : having or showing an unfair tendency to
>   believe that some people, ideas, etc., are better than others
>
> **[subjective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subjective)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : based on feelings or opinions rather than facts

Comment: I think I'm going to go with *cognitive bias*.

Answer (score 2):

The researcher's conclusion is ***invalid***.

> [**invalid**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invalid) (adjective)
>
> not valid, in particular. (especially of an argument, statement, or theory) not true because based on erroneous information or unsound reasoning.

You can also say that the researcher's conclusion is ***unsound***.

> [**unsound**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unsound) (adjective)
>
> not based on sound or reliable evidence or reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I propose [misrepresentative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misrepresent).

> Because the researcher was biased, he falsified<sup>1</sup> his data to match his expected outcome-- the conclusions are **misrepresentative** of the actual data collected.

I think this word has the proper ethical undertones- that the researcher did something purposeful to the data, not just that his inherent biases inadvertently affected the way he interpreted or collected the results.

You might also say the conclusions are *not reflective* of the true data, but this is more neutral.

---

<sup>1</sup> [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/falsify)

Answer (score 1):

**Unsubstantiated**

> Not supported or proven by evidence

Source: [Oxford Dictionary of English](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1950&lpg=PA1950&dq=%22Not+supported+or+proven+by+evidence%22&source=bl&ots=TZjwgukIzR&sig=yjlLYFqhqS2o7xk2Jsku2py6S1U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFjJWZ3JHPAhWFMGMKHZPBADkQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22Not%20supported%20or%20proven%20by%20evidence%22&f=false).

Comment: I added a link to an Oxford Dictionary that presents the definition you quote in your question. Please cite the source of any quotation you use in future answers.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! As Sven has said, add references to your answers to improve their quality, no one likes an **unsubstantiated** answer!

Comment: Good one  BladorthinTheGrey! Newbie here, I'll keep that in mind next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The results of the study can be termed as **inconclusive**.

> not leading to a firm conclusion or result; not ending doubt or dispute.

The researcher is being *biased*, his research lacks **objectivity**.

Comment: Ha ha, she drew conclusions all right!  But they were hogwash!

Answer (score 0):

Following gstats, I suggest ***falsified***.

> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/falsify) to make (something) false : to change (something) in order to make people believe something that is not true

This researcher's results are certainly biased, unsound, misrepresentative, and invalid, but this is all the result of her or his *falsified* conclusion.

Comment: I think *falsified* is when the person makes up the questionnaire responses.

Answer (score 0):

"Incongruent" seems like it could be the word for which you're searching.

There is a conclusion but it is not consistent (perhaps "inconsistent" instead) with the line of experimentation.

But the ethical issues of the situation described are paramount and would be what the qualifier should indicate rather than describing why the UNDESIRED conclusion was disgarded.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Could you add some references to back-up your answer and to give it extra clout?

Comment: You bring out a helpful point in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

*Scientifically bankrupt*

I am posting this as it just occurred to me and I would like to get others' reactions to this idea.  It is motivated by the phrase "morally bankrupt.*

Answer (score 0):

Selecting data that supports position is often called "[cherry picking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking)"

Answer (score -1):

If the researcher is making his selection based on the viewpoint of those sponsoring his research, then you could say **he knows which side of his bread is buttered**.

> Be aware of where one's best interests lie, as in Jerry always helps out his boss; he knows which side of his bread is buttered. This expression alludes to the more favorable, or buttered, side of bread and has been used metaphorically since the early 1500s.

know which side of one's bread is buttered. (n.d.). The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Retrieved September 15, 2016 from Dictionary.com website http://www.dictionary.com/browse/know-which-side-of-one-s-bread-is-buttered

Comment: Why was this voted down?  I think this happened in the Regnerus Affair.