# Expression for misrepresenting statistics

Tags: phrase-requests

Sometimes when a lot of data is gathered, an argument against the majority can rely on selecting the rarer case.

For example, a medical procedure which usually does more harm than good can be defended by statements from the few it has benefited.

Is there a word or expression for this? It could be "cherry-picking", but that doesn't signify the deception taking place.

Comment: Assuming it's an accepted fact that the procedure *usually does more harm than good*, it CAN'T be *defended by statements from the few it has benefited* - that's just straightforward "misrepresentation" (more appropriately in many contexts, "lying").

Comment: Does "an argument against the majority can rely on selecting the rarer case" mean that the _outliers are being weighted more heavily_?

Comment: @Cascabel in a statistical or otherwise scientific context, I think this could be misleading, because it might suggest that outliers are literally being weighted more heavily in an analysis or meta-analysis (of some medical intervention), which is a valid statistical procedure in some cases (but not what we have in mind here).

Comment: (as you may well know already!)

Comment: @legatrix Yeah...I was a little confused by the Q, as "cherry-picking" is the term I would normally use for this, but the OP seemed to be discounting it.

Comment: @Cascabel yeah, I agree cherry-picking is best, short of a longer explanation (which is what I would actually give).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What word describes interpreting evidence in such a way as to reach a desired conclusion?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29501/what-word-describes-interpreting-evidence-in-such-a-way-as-to-reach-a-desired-co/179030#179030) and  [Need word for situation where conclusion doesn't follow from the experimental data](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348584/need-word-for-situation-where-conclusion-doesnt-follow-from-the-experimental-da) and ...

Comment: [What is a word for deliberate dismissal of some facts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355379/what-is-a-word-for-deliberate-dismissal-of-some-facts/355495#355495)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for these suggested duplicates. While “cherry-picking” is one of the offered answers for some of these questions, they seem to differ, because the accepted answer for those would not be suitable here

Comment: @Cascabel not outliers, but the other side of the spectrum being weighted more heavily

Comment: @FumbleFingers misrepresentation is also an excellent candidate, thank you

Comment: 'Duplicates' are where the questions are near-identical (as here) and especially where [almost] all the answers in the newer thread have already been supplied. // 'Misrepresentation' is an extreme hypernym, referring to all outright lies and subtler distortions. **Confirmation Bias** is another good fit for your question as stated at the moment.

Comment: I'm no statistician, but I'd have thought the entire justification for identifying "outliers" in a dataset is so they can be given a ***lower*** weighting factor (or simply ignored) in subsequent analysis. In which context arguably one might say that the decision to label any given datum as an outlier potentially introduces "bias" (it's only an "outlier" because it doesn't fit in with prior expectations).

Answer (score 2):

*Cherry-picking* is the exact expression used when discussing this problem, including when deception is present. It falls under the general header of QRPs (questionable research practices) in psychology and other sciences---often pertaining specifically to statistical analysis---and came to the fore during the so-called replication crisis which has made great waves in the past 5 years. See the *Rationale* section at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preregistration_(science)#Rationale.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent link and answer. According to the article, cherry-picking is selective reporting of results, which I imagine is taking the best of the good (patient who recovered and plays in the NBA), not the opposite of the majority (95% had complications but a healthy case is presented). That’s the meaning I fear is lost when using this expression

Comment: OK, I see your point now! I guess that sounds like such malicious deception that it goes beyond anything there is a standard term for in scientific practice.

Comment: I'm still confused by this Q...